# "means of" vs "mean of"

Tags: phrases, idioms

When you use "means of" as a way to say a method eg. means of identification, do you always use **means** and not **mean**? Or does it depend on the subject? I have googled it but am still not sure.

Comment: Try looking up the words on this website and it's going to show you examples. http://corpus.byu.edu

Comment: As a noun, *mean* and *means* mean different things. This should be clear from a [dictionary definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/means). This might be a good question for our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Before asking a question such as this you should have consulted a dictionary to determine, eg, the difference between *mean* and *means*.  (And indicate what references you consulted -- "I googled it" doesn't hack it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always use *means*, which can be either singular ("a means of identification") or plural ("several means of identification").

The noun *mean* is a separate word, though it is related, and though its plural is also *means* (as in "the arithmetic and geometric means").